# how to apply validation in draftjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, draftjs

I have a form which includes email from, subject and text which uses drafts for rich text editor. I could validate other fields but how can i validate draftjs editor. When i click on editor to type, if it is left empty, it should show the error otherwise success like the one in attached screenshot.

Here is my code

```
function FieldGroup({ validationState, ...props }) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <FormGroup validationState={validationState}>
      <ControlLabel>{props.label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl {...props} />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}

class EmailTemplate extends React.Component {
  state = {
    emailFrom: ''
  };

  handleChange = event =>
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  render() {
    const { templateName, emailSubject, emailFrom } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        <FieldGroup
          id="formControlsText"
          name="emailFrom"
          type="email"
          label="Email From"
          placeholder="Enter Email From"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          validationState={emailFrom ? 'success' : 'error'}
          required
        />
        <AdminEditor />
        <Button type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default EmailTemplate;


render() {
  const { editorContent, contentState, editorState } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        initialContentState={rawContentState}
        wrapperClassName="home-wrapper"
        editorClassName="home-editor"
        onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
        toolbar={{
          history: { inDropdown: true },
          inline: { inDropdown: false },
          list: { inDropdown: true },
          link: { showOpenOptionOnHover: true },
          textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
          image: { uploadCallback: this.imageUploadCallBack }
        }}
        onContentStateChange={this.onEditorChange}
        placeholder="write text here..."
        spellCheck
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText()` to check if the user has entered any text in the editor and apply your styling accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onBlur` and `onFocus` mouse event of draft.js.

- `onBlur` handle will check for content of editor when user leave the
  editor and click somewhere else. if editor content is empty then it
  set `editorValidated` as false in state.
- `onFocus` handle will always set `editorValidated` as true. So there
  is no error when user starts typing again.

in `Editor` component you can use `editorValidated` to add your custom styling through css classes.

```
    function FieldGroup({ validationState, ...props }) {
      console.log(props);
      return (
        <FormGroup validationState={validationState}>
          <ControlLabel>{props.label}</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl {...props} />
        </FormGroup>
      );
    }

    class EmailTemplate extends React.Component {
      state = {
        emailFrom: '',
        editorValidated:true,
      };

      handleChange = event =>
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
      render() {
        const { templateName, emailSubject, emailFrom } = this.state;
        return (
          <form>
            <FieldGroup
              id="formControlsText"
              name="emailFrom"
              type="email"
              label="Email From"
              placeholder="Enter Email From"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              validationState={emailFrom ? 'success' : 'error'}
              required
            />
            <AdminEditor />
            <Button type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </form>
        );
      }
    }

    export default EmailTemplate;


    render() {
      const { editorContent, contentState, editorState } = this.state;
      return (
        <div>
          <Editor
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            initialContentState={rawContentState}
            wrapperClassName="home-wrapper"
            editorClassName=`home-editor ${(this.state.editorValidated)?'validated','not-validated'}`
            onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
            toolbar={{
              history: { inDropdown: true },
              inline: { inDropdown: false },
              list: { inDropdown: true },
              link: { showOpenOptionOnHover: true },
              textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
              image: { uploadCallback: this.imageUploadCallBack }
            }}
            onFocus={()=>{this.setState({editorValidated:true})}}
            onBlur={()=>{this.setState({editorValidated:(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText()!='')})}}
            onContentStateChange={this.onEditorChange}
            placeholder="write text here..."
            spellCheck
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```